# H2 database results different depending schema source

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, h2, liquibase

I save a number of big decimals in the database, marked with

‘’’precision = 4, scale = 16’’’ on the entity field.

When I create the database purely with hibernate create/create-drop, saving a value of ‘420’ will return me a value of ‘420’. All good.

When I create the schema using liquidate, with the exact same precision and scale, the value returned is ‘420.000000000000’.

I’m not too worried which one is returned, but for testing I need the value returned to be consistent.

Is there a way to tell hibernate to to trim values, or always return the full value, or even better adhere to the schema correctly in both places?

Both scenarios are run against an in memory H2 database. Hibernate verbalisation passes when using liquibase as the source.

Spring-boot 2.1.3
Hibernate 5.1
Liquibase 3.6.3
H2 1.4

Cheers
Bb

Comment: Regardless of what the solution is, if you don't care about the precision, you shouldn't be testing for it. I'd strongly recommend using `compareTo` instead of `equals` for `BigDecimals` in your tests

Comment: Thanks, yes I do for mathematical operations, but as part of cucumber tests I am printing strings, which then differ based on the underlying hibernate/db creation combination, removing multi platform/vendor testing